# Relationship Gas ORM Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, orm

I am new to Gas ORM, I have two tables roles and users, A user only has one role
How can i display role name and not role id in user view. I am using GAS ORM and codeigniter

**Role Model**

```
    function _init()
{
    self::$relationships = array(
                            'user' => ORM::has_many('\\Model\\User_model'),
                    );
    self::$fields = array('role_id' => ORM::field('auto[11]'),
                           'name' => ORM::field('char[255]', array('required','max_length[255]')),);
            }
```

**User Model**

```
function _init()
        {
                self::$relationships = array(
                        'role' => ORM::belongs_to('\\Model\\Role_model'),
                );
                self::$fields = array(
                        'user_id'                    =>           ORM::field('auto[255]'),
                        'email'                    =>             ORM::field('email[255]'),
                        'name'                    =>              ORM::field('char[255]'),
                        'username'                 =>             ORM::field('char[255]', array('required','max_length[255]')),
                        'password'              =>                ORM::field('char[255]'),
                        'active'                 =>              ORM::field('numeric[255]'),
                );
        }
```

In my **View** i Display users as

```
<?php $row_count = 0; foreach ($users as $user){ $row_count = ++$row_count;?>
                  <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $row_count; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $user->role_id . " " . $user->name; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $user->username; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $user->role($user->role_id)->name; ?></td>
                    <td><?php if($user->active == 1) echo "Active"; else echo "Inactive"; ?></td>
                    <td><span class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editUser" onclick="edit('<?php echo $user->user_id; ?>')"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>&nbsp;Edit</span>
                      <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="rm('<?php echo $user->name; ?>','<?php echo $user->user_id; ?>');"><span class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>&nbsp;Delete</span></a>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                    <?php } ?>
```

I get an **error** while displaying the role name

Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1

SELECT * FROM `tbl_roles` WHERE `tbl_roles`.`role_id` IN ()

Filename: third_party/gas/classes/core.php

Line Number: 850

Answer (score 0):

I have a same problem with this.

If you use primary_key setting, try this.

orm.php

```
    /* We wanna use foreign_key always.
    if (empty($this->primary_key))
    {
    */
        if ( ! empty($this->foreign_key))
        {
            // Validate foreign keys for consistency naming convention recognizer
            $foreign_key = array();

            foreach($this->foreign_key as $namespace => $fk)
            {
                $foreign_key[strtolower($namespace)] = $fk;
            }

            $this->foreign_key = $foreign_key;
        }
        else
        {
            // If so far we didnt have any keys yet, 
            // then hopefully someone is really follow Gas convention
            // while he define his entity relationship (yes, YOU!)
            foreach ($this->meta->get('entities') as $name => $entity)
            {
                if ($entity['type'] == 'belongs_to')
                {
                    $child_name     = $entity['child'];
                    $child_instance = new $child_name;
                    $child_table    = $child_instance->table;
                    $child_key      = $child_instance->primary_key;

                    $this->foreign_key[strtolower($child_name)] = $child_table.'_'.$child_key;
                }
            }
        }
    //}
```

Comment: A better answer for this is found here.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37812459/multiple-foreign-key-to-same-table-gas-orm