# Gas orm 2 relationships : empty IN SQL clause

Tags: php, codeigniter, orm

### Edit : Solved

I found the answer on an [other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40992022/7769576) : in fact this error was just a side effect of a bug inn Gas orm class.
Whad I did :

1. Open `application/third_party/gas/classes/orm.php`
2. Modify  the **line 191** as shown below :

**Before:**

```
if (empty($this->primary_key))
```

**After:**

```php
if (! empty($this->primary_key))
```

*Note : For this patch to work you have to always specify the `$primary_key` in your models.*

---

### Original question

I am trying to use Gas ORM 2.1 with CodeIgniter 3.1.4 (PHP 7) and I have trouble using relationships : it seems that the foreign key is not specified in the SQL request :

```
A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1

SELECT * FROM `Client` WHERE `Client`.`id_cli` IN ()

Filename: third_party/gas/classes/core.php

Line Number: 850
```

The Relationship is as follow :

- A client can have 0 or many contact
- A contact is related to one client

The **table** is filled as follow :

```sql
mysql> select * from Contact;
+-------+-----------+--------+--------+
| id_ct | prenom_ct | nom_ct | id_cli |
+-------+-----------+--------+--------+
|     1 | bonbeur   | jean   |      1 |
|     2 | lapraline | toto   |      1 |
|     3 | cover     | harry  |      2 |
+-------+-----------+--------+--------+
3 rows in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> select * from Client;
+--------+-------------+------------+
| id_cli | nom_cli     | nomasa_cli |
+--------+-------------+------------+
|      1 | My Client 1 | MC1        |
|      2 | My Client 2 | MC2        |
+--------+-------------+------------+
2 rows in set (0,00 sec)
```

The **contact** model is as follows :

```php
<?php

namespace Model;

use \Gas\Core;
use \Gas\ORM;

class Contact extends ORM {

        public $table = "Contact";
        public $primary_key = 'id_ct';

        function _init()
        {

                self::$relationships = array (
                        'id_cli'          =>     ORM::belongs_to('\\Model\\Client')
                );

                self::$fields = array(
                        'id_ct'         => ORM::field('auto[10]'),
                        'prenom_ct'     => ORM::field('char[100]', array('required','max_length[100]')),
                        'nom_ct'        => ORM::field('char[100]', array('required','max_length[100]')),
                );
        }
}
```

The **client** model is as follows :

```php
<?php

namespace Model;

use \Gas\Core;
use \Gas\ORM;

class Client extends ORM {

        public $primary_key = 'id_cli';
        public $table = "Client";

        function _init()
        {

                self::$relationships = array (
                        'Contact'         =>     ORM::has_many('\\Model\\Contact')
                );

                self::$fields = array(
                        'id_cli'        => ORM::field('auto[10]'),
                        'nom_cli'       => ORM::field('char[250]', array('required','max_length[250]')),
                        'nomasa_cli'    => ORM::field('char[25]', array('required','max_length[25]')),
                );
        }
}
```

The **controller** is as follows :

```php
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Contact extends CI_Controller {

    /**
     * Index Page for this controller.
     */
    public function index() {
        return $this->listing();
    }

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // Your own constructor code
    }

    public function listing() {
        $data["contacts"] = Model\Contact::all();
        foreach($data['contacts'] as $c) {
            $cli = $c->id_cli();
            /*XXX*/ echo "<pre>";var_dump($cli);echo "</pre>";/*XXX*/
        }
        $this->render->show('contact/listing', $data);
    }

}
```

**What I would like is to obtain the client related to the contact.**

The error occurs before the `var_dump` (so nothing is displayed, except the error message).
My DB tables don't respect the Gas ORM naming convention :

- I use uppercase letter in table names (cf. `$table` in models)
- I have a numeric field as primary key but its name is `id_<suffix>` where `<suffix>` is table related (cf. `$primary_key` in models)

Based on this, I'm not sure if I'm using Gas correctly.

---

**References:**

Gas ORM documentation: gasorm-doc.taufanaditya.com

Code igniter website: codeigniter.com

---

*PS : Sorry, not enough reputation to include pics, or insert real links.*

Answer (score 0):

Solved : Refer to the *Edit* section above.